# How can I simplify my dict statements into one statement?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to combine my two dictionaries to read easier and simplify my code but every time I merge them I keep getting errors or the items not properly reading.

```
rooms = {
'Stable': {'West': 'Foyer'},
'Foyer': {'South': 'Great Hall'},
'Great Hall': {'South': 'Dining Room', 'East': 'Study', 'West': 'Balcony’, ‘North’: ‘Foyer'},
'Study': {'North': 'Library', 'West': 'Great Hall'},
'Dining Room': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Kitchen'},
'Library': {'South': 'Study'},
'Kitchen': {'West': 'Dining Room'},
'Balcony': {'East': 'Great Hall'},
}
items = {
'Foyer': 'Shield',
'Great Hall': 'Sword',
'Study': 'Armor',
'Library': 'Spell Book',
'Dining Room': 'Helmet',
'Kitchen': 'Cooked Chicken',
'Balcony': 'Dark Knight',

}
```

Comment: what do you want the output to look like?

Comment: The output is part of the text based game i am working on for my project in class. I was given feedback that i needed to combine the two dictionaries for easier readability. When I combine the two dictionaries into this 'Great Hall': {'South': 'Dining Room', 'item': 'Helmet', 'East': 'Study', 'item': 'Armor', 'West': 'Balcony’, 'item': 'Dark Knight', ‘North’: ‘Foyer'}, I get errors or the item doesn't prompt when executing the code. I would be happy to send you the whole thing if it is easier to see my entire code. @constantstranger

Comment: It doesn't make sense to combine them; there's a clear separation of "things" between the two

Comment: You can do `rooms, items = {..}, {..}`, but that will not be easier to read.

Comment: The structure you presented in your comment doesn't make sense because you have to know the direction in the first place. What if I wanted to go North from the Stable? That's a KeyError that I can't know about as a player

Comment: Actually, on further reading of your proposed structure in the comment, you've avoided a big trap which would lead to massive duplication. Perhaps without realising it, you've used normalisation on your data - I suggest you go back and tell your instructor that you've used [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) in this case

Comment: @roganjosh The dict in their comment doesn't even work, you can't have multiple `'item'` keys in the same dict. They'd need `NotStr('item')` for that (who knew that that thing would become useful so quickly :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy Oh man, `NotStr` is already haunting me? :P There are problems with this setup for sure, but I really disagree with the advice that's been given.

Answer (score 0):

> *`{'South': 'Dining Room', 'item': 'Helmet', 'East': 'Study', 'item': 'Armor', 'West': 'Balcony’, 'item': 'Dark Knight', ‘North’: ‘Foyer'}`*

the structure suggested in your comment is not valid (as others have already pointed out), but there are still many ways to combine the two dictionaries.

---

##### Suggestion 1: <kbd>room -> direction -> (room, item)</kbd>

```py
rooms_items = {rk: {
    dk: (drv, items.get(drv)) for dk, drv in rv.items()
} for rk, rv in rooms.items()}
```

will have `rooms_items` as

> ```py
> { 'Stable': {'West': ('Foyer', 'Shield')},
>   'Foyer': {'South': ('Great Hall', 'Sword')},
>   'Great Hall': {'South': ('Dining Room', 'Helmet'),
>     'East': ('Study', 'Armor'),
>     'West': ('Balcony', 'Dark Knight'),
>     'North': ('Foyer', 'Shield')},
>   'Study': {'North': ('Library', 'Spell Book'),
>     'West': ('Great Hall', 'Sword')},
>   'Dining Room': {'North': ('Great Hall', 'Sword'),
>     'East': ('Kitchen', 'Cooked Chicken')},
>   'Library': {'South': ('Study', 'Armor')},
>   'Kitchen': {'West': ('Dining Room', 'Helmet')},
>   'Balcony': {'East': ('Great Hall', 'Sword')}}
> ```

---

##### Suggestion 2: <kbd>room -> {item, direction_room, direction_item}</kbd>

```
{rk: dict(sorted([
    *[(f'{dk}_room', drv) for dk, drv in rv.items()],
    *[(f'{dk}_item', items.get(drv)) for dk, drv in rv.items()],
    ('item', items.get(rk))
 ], reverse=True)) for rk, rv in rooms.items()}
```

would return

> ```py
> { 'Stable': {'item': None, 'West_room': 'Foyer', 'West_item': 'Shield'},
>   'Foyer': {  'item': 'Shield', 
>               'South_room': 'Great Hall', 'South_item': 'Sword'  },
>   'Great Hall': { 'item': 'Sword',
>                   'West_room': 'Balcony', 'West_item': 'Dark Knight',
>                   'South_room': 'Dining Room', 'South_item': 'Helmet',
>                   'North_room': 'Foyer', 'North_item': 'Shield',
>                   'East_room': 'Study', 'East_item': 'Armor' },
>   'Study': {  'item': 'Armor',
>               'West_room': 'Great Hall', 'West_item': 'Sword',
>               'North_room': 'Library', 'North_item': 'Spell Book'  },
>   'Dining Room': {  'item': 'Helmet',
>                     'North_room': 'Great Hall', 'North_item': 'Sword',
>                     'East_room': 'Kitchen', 'East_item': 'Cooked Chicken'  },
>   'Library': {  'item': 'Spell Book',
>                 'South_room': 'Study', 'South_item': 'Armor'  },
>   'Kitchen': {  'item': 'Cooked Chicken',
>                 'West_room': 'Dining Room', 'West_item': 'Helmet'  },
>   'Balcony': {  'item': 'Dark Knight',
>                 'East_room': 'Great Hall', 'East_item': 'Sword'  } }
> ```

---

##### Suggestion 3: <kbd>room -> {item, direction -> {room, item}}</kbd>

```py
{rk: {'item':  items.get(rk), **{dk: {
    'room': drv, 'item': items.get(drv)
} for dk, drv in rv.items()}} for rk, rv in rooms.items()}
```

returns

> ```py
> { 'Stable': {'item': None, 'West': {'room': 'Foyer', 'item': 'Shield'}},
>   'Foyer': {  'item': 'Shield',
>               'South': {'room': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'Sword'}  },
>   'Great Hall': { 'item': 'Sword',
>                   'South': {'room': 'Dining Room', 'item': 'Helmet'},
>                   'East': {'room': 'Study', 'item': 'Armor'},
>                   'West': {'room': 'Balcony', 'item': 'Dark Knight'},
>                   'North': {'room': 'Foyer', 'item': 'Shield'} },
>   'Study': {  'item': 'Armor',
>               'North': {'room': 'Library', 'item': 'Spell Book'},
>               'West': {'room': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'Sword'}  },
>   'Dining Room': {  'item': 'Helmet',
>                     'North': {'room': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'Sword'},
>                     'East': {'room': 'Kitchen', 'item': 'Cooked Chicken'}  },
>   'Library': {  'item': 'Spell Book',
>                 'South': {'room': 'Study', 'item': 'Armor'}  },
>   'Kitchen': {  'item': 'Cooked Chicken',
>                 'West': {'room': 'Dining Room', 'item': 'Helmet'}  },
>   'Balcony': {  'item': 'Dark Knight',
>                 'East': {'room': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'Sword'}  } }
> ```

---

Once you decide on a [valid] structure for the combined data, you can figure out how to build it.

Answer (score 0):

You said you were told you *"needed to combine the two dictionaries for easier readability"*. Apparently, they'd find it easier to read if each room's whole data were in one place instead of spread over multiple dicts. So instead of

```
'Foyer': {'South': 'Great Hall'},
```

in one dict and

```
'Foyer': 'Shield',
```

in another, just combine that:

```
'Foyer': {'item': 'Shield', 'South': 'Great Hall'},
```

You could combine your dicts like that with this code:

```
for k, v in items.items():
    rooms[k]['item'] = v
del items
```

But really that would be missing the point. You should *write* that combined dict *instead* of your two dicts. Then you have that better readability.

If your code would somehow benefit from your two dicts, you can easily compute them from that *one* dict containing the *whole* game configuration. You don't necessarily need to use that game configuration directly.